# Redshift - Extract root keys from the JSON with Python UDF

Tags: python, json, amazon-redshift

In Redshift, if we can extract the JSON using [json_extract_path_text](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT.html) functions. But sometimes, if we don't know how many keys we have in the column, then its difficult to know the list of keys.

Need a Scalar or Python UDF to make this easier.

### Source Data:

```
  {
    "_id": "5d628b01132beadd7e2ede3e",
    "index": 0,
    "guid": "a2a351a1-3cca-40e1-8b2b-1197e76373fb",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$3,771.66",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 28,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": "Araceli Lang",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "OLYMPIX",
    "email": "aracelilang@olympix.com",
    "phone": "+1 (817) 552-3696",
    "address": "817 Concord Street, Zeba, Alabama, 5127",
    "about": "Enim nulla sit ea qui exercitation aute do cupidatat mollit incididunt deserunt aute in. Culpa anim eu cillum esse ipsum veniam amet veniam enim nostrud eu et. Enim aute ea duis enim in consectetur nulla amet fugiat id nisi non aliquip. Proident fugiat culpa aute minim dolor esse reprehenderit",
    "registered": "2018-12-27T10:15:14 -06:-30",
    "latitude": 20.920064,
    "longitude": 62.561981,
    "tags": [
        "excepteur",
        "magna",
        "eiusmod",
        "esse",
        "aute",
        "occaecat",
        "consectetur"
    ],
    "friends": [{
            "id": 0,
            "name": "Schneider Combs"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Roseann Buckner"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Eaton Reid"
        }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Araceli Lang! You have 10 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "banana"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my simple Python UDF to solve this.

```py
 create or replace function json_list_root_keys (j varchar(max))
        returns varchar(max)
        stable as $$
          import json
          if not j:
            return None
          try:
            js = json.loads(j)
          except ValueError:
            return None
          if len(js) == 0:
            return None
          return json.dumps(js.keys())
        $$ language plpythonu;
```

```sql
create table j_test (j_col varchar(max));

insert into j_test values ('{"_id":"5d628b01132beadd7e2ede3e","index":0,"guid":"a2a351a1-3cca-40e1-8b2b-1197e76373fb","isActive":true,"balance":"$3,771.66","picture":"http://placehold.it/32x32","age":28,"eyeColor":"blue","name":"AraceliLang","gender":"female","company":"OLYMPIX","email":"aracelilang@olympix.com","phone":"+1(817)552-3696","address":"817ConcordStreet,Zeba,Alabama,5127","about":"Enimnullasiteaquiexercitationautedocupidatatmollitincididuntdeseruntautein.Culpaanimeucillumesseipsumveniamametveniamenimnostrudeuet.Enimauteeaduiseniminconsecteturnullaametfugiatidnisinonaliquip.Proidentfugiatculpaauteminimdoloressereprehenderit.","registered":"2018-12-27T10:15:14-06:-30","latitude":20.920064,"longitude":62.561981,"tags":["excepteur","magna","eiusmod","esse","aute","occaecat","consectetur"],"friends":[{"id":0,"name":"SchneiderCombs"},{"id":1,"name":"RoseannBuckner"},{"id":2,"name":"EatonReid"}],"greeting":"Hello,AraceliLang!Youhave10unreadmessages.","favoriteFruit":"banana"}');

select json_list_root_keys(j_col) from j_test ;
```

### Output:

```
["guid", "index", "favoriteFruit", "latitude", "company", "email", "picture", "tags", "registered", "eyeColor", "phone", "address", "friends", "isActive", "a
bout", "balance", "name", "gender", "age", "greeting", "longitude", "_id"]
```

#### Note:

make sure you don't have any `\r \n` characters. Else it'll not return any value.

Similarly, if anyone interested in writing a Scalar UDF, please share that as well.